# Azure servicebus trigger won't fire locally form one function, but identical new template to same queue works from another

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

i have a solution with a number of different functions, 3 of which are service bus triggers to queues.

Recently, they've began to fail to fire when a message is available on the queue for any of these 3 items.
as a test.

I created a new function in a different solution to the same sb queue and this picks up the items fully.

The code is identical to what has been deployed to azure and is currently functioning properly, but for some reason i'm no longer able to debug locally for dev and test work. All conenction strings have already been configured on the local.settings.json file and on the test trigger function are identical to the other function that doesn't fire

I've had a look around the site but this doesn't seem to be something mentioned before

It's also not connected to `TransportType=AmqpWebSockets` as i already have this defined on the connection string for both functions

Answer (score 1):

FYI for any others, I've found that even with ampqWebSockets set on the endpoint connection string, I needed to include the below on the host.json file locally for the trigger to fire.
I'm not sure why it wasn't needed on a test function using the trigger template that worked, however adding the below worked on my actual solution:

```
"extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "transportType": "amqpWebSockets"
    }
  }
```